# AngularJS - Directive wrapping without losing connection to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, directive

Is there a way for not losing connection to the current controller when you are wrapping data with a directive ?

My problem is, that the directive within the wrapped template has no connection to the outside controller any more and so I can not execute the function.

Wrapping Directive:

```
myApp.directive('wrapContent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            model:                      "=",
            datas:                      "="
        },
        templateUrl: "./any/template.php",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            // any
        }
    };
});
```

Directive within the wrapped Template

```
myApp.directive('doAction', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).click(function(e) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.doAction);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Conroller:

```
lmsApp.controller('OutsideController', function ($scope){
    $sope.sayHello = function() {
        alert("hello");
     };
});
```

HTML where I want to execute the function (template.php):

```
<div>
     <do-action="sayHello()"></do-action>
</div>
```

How I call the `wrapContent` directive which is outside (**Updated**):

```
<div ng-controller="OutsideController">
        <wrap-content model="any" datas="data_any"></wrap-content>
</div>
```

How can I execute the `sayHello()` function?

Thank you for your help! I would appreciate every answer.

Comment: how are you  calling your `wrapContent` directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrapContent directive will be processed with the scope of controller.
DoAction directive will be processed with the isolateScope of wrapContent directive.

Solution1:
Get a reference to the sayHello function in wrapContent using '&' and execute it in event handler.

Solution2:
Instead of using scope in your event handler, use scope.$parent.

Comment: If I use $parent I have to define the function in the parent directive once more. Am I right?

Comment: @BernhardPointner you don't have to.

Comment: But this `scope.$parent.sayHello();` does not work. -> undefined function

Comment: It worked for me.. I tried with angular v1.3.5. Which version did you try? Could you please create a plunker if possible?

Comment: It was one $parent too low -> `scope.$parent.$parent`. Now it works!

Comment: Try this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspect/cidepfmbgngpdapgncfhpecbdhmnnemf/related?hl=en-US&gl=IN  to debug your angularjs applications.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `sayHallo` function to your parent directive using `&`

```
myApp.directive('wrapContent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            model:                      "=",
            datas:                      "=",
            sayHallo: "&"
        },
        templateUrl: "./any/template.php",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            // any
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="OutsideController">
        <wrap-content model="any" datas="data_any" sayHallo="sayHallo()"></wrap-content>
</div>
```

Then in your child directive, you will have `sayHallo` in your scope, to call it just do it this:

```
myApp.directive('doAction', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             scope.sayHallo();
        }
    }
});
```

And you dont need pass it again. So your child directive should looks like this:

```
<div>
     <do-action></do-action>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use all your parent model functions,without passing each function. In your child directive,just use `scope.model` to have access to model attributes and functions.

```
myApp.directive('doAction', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             scope.model.sayHallo();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thans levi! - Good idea - that is what i searched for. It is like passing the function through the wrapping. The only problem is that I have to do this with all my functions I have within the wrapped content :(

Comment: And with your second solution I do not have to pass any function through the wrapping ?

Comment: The `scope.model` is an empty object ? :/

Comment: you pass it to your parent directive `model:  "="` right?

Comment: At the parent directive, yes.

Comment: @BernhardPointner well, you can use in your child directive.